# Bootstrap display form labels inline

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to have 2 form labels display inline with Twitter Bootstrap.

The form inputs display inline just fine because of their input-large class. How do I achieve the same behaviour on my labels? I want the labels to display inline and on top of their corresponding input fields.

Here's my HTML:

```
<div class="control-group">
      <label class="control-label" for="likedcolors">Kleuren die u wel aanspreken*:</label>
      <label class="control-label" for="dislikedcolors">Kleuren die u niet aanspreken*:</label>
      <div class="controls">
        <input type="text" class="input-large" name="likedcolors" id="likedcolors">
        <input type="text" class="input-large" name="dislikedcolors" id="dislikedcolors">
      </div>
</div>
```

@Lykos, with your answer the labels are looking like this:

[image]

Ideally the labels should look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like that ?

```
<form>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span6">
            <label class="control-label" for="likedcolors">Kleuren die u wel aanspreken*:</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <input type="text" class="input-large" name="likedcolors" id="likedcolors"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="span6">
            <label class="control-label" for="dislikedcolors">Kleuren die u niet aanspreken*:</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <input type="text" class="input-large" name="dislikedcolors" id="dislikedcolors"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hMga4/1/

Comment: please see the last image in my question. I'd like to have the labels and input fields displayed inline, with the labels above the input fields

Comment: which bootstrap is ? if 2.x use`span6` else use `col-md-6` instead

Comment: which version of bootstrap you are using ??

Comment: I'm using version 2.3.2

Comment: I think I know why it's not working. My form doesn't have the total width required for the 2 inputs with such a great margin in between. Your code is working fine

Comment: you should better add a specific class for them, otherwise you could broke others span6

Answer (score 0):

Please do this in case you're using Bootstrap 3:

```
<form>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="likedcolors">Kleuren die u wel aanspreken*:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="likedcolors" id="likedcolors"/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
           <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="dislikedcolors">Kleuren die u niet aanspreken*:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="dislikedcolors" id="dislikedcolors"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

in case you use Bootstrap 2 replace the class col-md-6 with class span6. Just remember that you columns should end up to 12.

Comment: Not exactly what I was looking for. I shall update the question to be more clear what I'd like to achieve

Comment: You are not closing your form group divs :)